# Circuit for voltage division and DC shift doesn't work

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, ac, dc, filter

I've connected the circuit below on a breadboard and tested it in the lab:

[image]

Components:

- \$R_{1}=1\,M\Omega,\;R_{2}=40\,k\Omega,\;R_{3}=R_{4}=R_{5}=R_{7}=R_{8}=20\,k\Omega,\;R_{6}=49.9\,k\Omega\thickapprox50\,k\Omega,\;R_{9}=R_{10}=10\,k\Omega,\;R_{11}=5.1\,k\Omega\thickapprox5\,k\Omega,\;R_{12}=1\,k\Omega,\;R_{13}=R_{14}=R_{16}=R_{17}=R_{18}=R_{19}=2\,k\Omega,\;R_{15}=5\,k\Omega\$

$$$$

- \$C_{1}=470\,\mu F,\;C_{2}=1\,\mu F\$

$$$$

- \$V_{CC}=15\,V,\;V_{EE}=-15\,V\$
  $$$$
- op-amps are of the type LM358P.
  $$$$

The upper part takes the DC component of an input signal through a passive low-pass filter, divide it by 5 through the voltage-divider network (note that R3 and R4 are in parallel), then add 2.5 V to it.

The lower part take the AC component of an input signal through capacitor, divide it by approximately 10 through the voltage-divider network (note that R12 and R13 are in parallel), then add 2.5 V to it.

The problem is that the output appears completely different from the theoretical values:

- For the upper circuit, when the input was a DC voltage of 5 V, the
  output was around 10 V instead of 3.5.
- For the bottom circuit, when the input was a sine wave, the output
  was completely distorted. It couldn't be recognized as a sine wave.

I don't know where the problem could be. The simulation results of the circuit give results as expected.

Comment: It would be nice to have component values on the schematic.  Do you have bypass caps?  Follow the signal through the circuit and see where it "goes wrong". That will help identify the  problem area.

Comment: Measure the voltages at various points (especially the outputs of the op-amps) to see where they deviate from what you expect. 1M is a pretty high resistor for a 470uF electrolytic cap, but that would tend to reduce the output voltage. It will also cause a bit of offset because of the bias current.

Comment: What is the dc resistance of your source signal? Input bias currents are going to play havoc with any accuracy given the 1 Mohm resistor in the DC circuit.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ,George Herold For the upper circuit, the error started from the junction between R1 and C1. There, the voltage is reduced instead of being not affected by the low-pass filter (since the input is a DC signal). The second point was at the junction between R2 and R3 (the voltage-divider); The voltage at that junction seemed to be increased rather than being reduced by the voltage-divider. That was weird!

Comment: @Andyaka I chose R1 to be 1M because I wanted to reject any frequency higher than zero (approximately) but I can't figure out how it can affect the circuit negatively.

Comment: I know why you chose it but you haven't factored in input bias currents of 100 nA+

Comment: @Andyaka Yes because I don't know about them in fact. I think that 1M would limit the current more than other lower resistors not the opposite. However, if I replaced the 1M resistor with 100K one for example, would that solve the problem?

Comment: It's not causing anything other than maybe a 0.2V offset and it certainly won't be causing the big problem you have. Bias currents are not altered (within reason) by making the resistor value different hence bigger values means more offset voltage error.

Comment: You need to edit the picture to add measured voltage levels at each op-amp output to get any further with this. Saying there is an unspecified error means zilch. Mark up the diagram above with actual measured values.

Comment: What kind of capacitor is that 470uF part? Unless it's the size of a thermos it's probably got significant leakage, and may be polarized.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't have measurement tools right now, but I may do so if I couldn't solve the problem tomorrow.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think that this is the capacitor I'm using : http://hxcapacitor.com/UploadCont/2016/01/20160110234202232.pdf

Comment: That cap has a lot of leakage and is polarized (almost for sure) so it should not be used in this circuit.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Aha. So I should use a ceramic capacitor whose legs are of the same length, right?

Comment: You won't find a ceramic capacitor that high value. Maybe you should settle for a higher frequency.

Comment: Film capacitors are well suited for precision applications; electrolytic ones are garbage, with all sorts of nonideal behaviour.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Does using an **active** low-pass filter solve the capacitor leakage problem?

Comment: It's more the frequency you are trying to reach - 0.0003Hz cutoff. You would need a film or ceramic capacitor, very high value resistors and much better op-amps to pull that off. At those frequencies digital solutions are usually better.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany **1.** If I changed the cutoff frequency to 1.5Hz -for example-, and accordingly used a resistor of 100k and a non-polarized capacitor of 1uF, would that solve the problem? **2.** Additionally, with these changes, will the low-pass filter still pass only the DC portion of the input? I mean for a signal with frequency higher than ,let's say, 15Hz?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Cutoff is 1/2*pi*R*C = 1.6Hz for your example, so 15Hz would mostly be attenuated.